# Ctrl k+D not working on last microsft vs update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, blazor, code-formatting

After last update of Microsoft VS ctrl K+D for format code not working for **razor page** although it format cs page

I tried to format form **Edit-Advanced-format document** but the code didn't format

Then i check if run code clean up on save and its checked, so i repair Microsoft vs but i still have the same problem[image]
[image]

please help me to find solution

Comment: There may be an issue with the shortcut key settings. Usually you can refer to the following steps first:Tools=>Environmrnt=>Keyboard. Select the corresponding programming language in "Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme" (for example, if I use C#, choose Visual C# 2005), and then click Reset. If this doesn't work for you please let me know